# Is xVal obsolete with MVC 2?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, xval

Now that built-in validation is supported with MVC 2 framework, should we be using it instead?  Are there any advantages that xVal has over MVC 2 validation?

The main reason I ask is that we have a couple MVC sites that use it, and it appears xVal is no longer being maintained/supported.  If this is the case, I'd like to start changing our sites over to use MVC 2 validation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jQuery validation scripts included with MVC2 are fully supported by Microsoft, so I would prefer them over third-party scripts, especially ones that no one is actively supporting.  The [xVal Codeplex site](http://xval.codeplex.com/) clearly lists xVal as only supported with MVC1.0.

Comment: Thanks, Dave.  I'm not sure how I missed that, but that definitely clears up any doubts I had. Actually, on second look, it looks like that notice may have just been posted a couple days ago?