# xval vs MVC 3.0 validations

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, xval, asp.net-mvc-3

I was wondering if anyone has any opinions regarding the usage of xVal or MVC 3.0 model validation? I originally started using xVal because of its ability to validate both client and server side but the project appears to be dead (perhaps dormant is a better word) and it appears that validation in MVC 2.0 and 3.0 has greatly improved. What are the advantages, if any, to using xval over MVC3.0 validation and vice versa?

Any advice is appreciated,

Thank you

JP

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4087664/is-xval-obsolete-with-mvc-2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is no advantage of using xVal for MVC 3.0 over the built-in support. The creators of xVal even say this on their homepage: [xVal's CodePlex site](http://xval.codeplex.com/):

> Important: xVal is recommended for use
>   only with ASP.NET MVC 1.0
>
> If you're using ASP.NET MVC 2.0 or
>   later, the framework has built-in
>   support for generating client-side
>   validation logic directly from model
>   metadata. You can still use xVal if
>   you wish, but it won't be actively
>   developed or supported.

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I'd never seen this recommendation. That is pretty definitive!